# How to assign a random weight to edges in networkx, like weight of edge (a, a) = 0 and weight of edge (a, b) = K, where K is some random number

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am working on weighted graphs and I would like to assign a random weight for the edges of the graph, such that,

```
 weight of edge(a, a) = 0
 weight of (a, b) = weight of edge(b, a) = K
```

where `K` is some random number. This goes on for all the edges of the graphs.

For that, I am using `random.randint()` method. I am actually using the logic of sum. If sum of both the edges is same, then assign some random integer.

Here is my code,

```py
nodelist = list(range(1, num_nodes + 1))
edgelist = []
for i in nodelist:
    for j in nodelist:
        if i == j:
            edgelist.append((i, j, 0))
        if (i != j and sum((i, j)) == sum((j, i))):
            rand = random.randint(5, 25)
            edgelist.append((i, j, rand))
print(edgelist)
```

Actual result,

```
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 18), (1, 3, 6), (2, 1, 13), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 21), (3, 1, 20), (3, 2, 17), (3, 3, 0)]
```

Expected result,

```
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, K), (1, 3, H), (2, 1, K), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, P), (3, 1, H), (3, 2, P), (3, 3, 0)]
```

where, `K`, `H`, `P` are some random integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ordering of the result is not important following code gives the desired output:

```py
import random
num_nodes = 3
nodelist = list(range(1, num_nodes + 1))
edgelist = []
for i in nodelist:
    for j in nodelist:
        if j > i:
            break
        if i == j:
            edgelist.append((i, j, 0))
        else:
            rand = random.randint(5, 25)
            edgelist.append((i, j, rand))
            edgelist.append((j, i, rand))
print(edgelist)
# [(1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 7), (1, 2, 7), (2, 2, 0), (3, 1, 18), (1, 3, 18), (3, 2, 13), (2, 3, 13), (3, 3, 0)]
```

In case you need the edges sorted, simply use:

```py
print(sorted(edgelist))
# [(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 20), (1, 3, 16), (2, 1, 20), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 23), (3, 1, 16), (3, 2, 23), (3, 3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out something interesting. Say below matrix shows edges in a complete graph of `5` nodes,

```
[1, 1]  [1, 2]  [1, 3]  [1, 4]  [1, 5]
[2, 1]  [2, 2]  [2, 3]  [2, 4]  [2, 5]
[3, 1]  [3, 2]  [3, 3]  [3, 4]  [3, 5]
[4, 1]  [4, 2]  [4, 3]  [4, 4]  [4, 5]
[5, 1]  [5, 2]  [5, 3]  [5, 4]  [5, 5]
```

now, moving right side from `principal diagonal`, we have lists whose first element is less than second element. We just got to target them and `append` new random weight to it.

Here is my code,

```
nodelist = list(range(1, num_nodes + 1))
edgelist = []
for i in nodelist:
    for j in nodelist:
        edgelist.append([i, j])

p = 0
eff_edgelist = []
while p < len(edgelist):
    if edgelist[p][0] <= edgelist[p][1]:
        eff_edgelist.append(edgelist[p])
    p += 1

for i in eff_edgelist:
    if i[0] == i[1]:
        i.append(0)
    else:
        i.append(random.randint(5, 50))
eff_edgelist = [tuple(i) for i in eff_edgelist]

for i in list(G.edges(data=True)):
    print([i])
```

and the result,

```
[(1, 1, {'weight': 0})]
[(1, 2, {'weight': 12})]
[(1, 3, {'weight': 37})]
[(1, 4, {'weight': 38})]
[(1, 5, {'weight': 6})]
[(2, 2, {'weight': 0})]
[(2, 3, {'weight': 12})]
[(2, 4, {'weight': 40})]
[(2, 5, {'weight': 8})]
[(3, 3, {'weight': 0})]
[(3, 4, {'weight': 15})]
[(3, 5, {'weight': 38})]
[(4, 4, {'weight': 0})]
[(4, 5, {'weight': 41})]
[(5, 5, {'weight': 0})]
```

and if you check, `print(G[2][1])`, the output will be `{'weight': 12}`,

which means `weight of edge(a, b) = weight of edge(b, a)`.

Comment: Do you need only an undirected graph? `Networkx` takes care about the edge weights for that case, e.g. adding edge (1,2, weight=3) will result in a weighted edge from 2 to 1 with weight 3, too.

Comment: Yes, I needed undirected graph. I just needed random assignments of weights. Previously I wanted `edge(a. b)` and `edge(b, a)` to have same weights. I was unaware of the fact that `Networkx` would take care of that. Thank you for your response. It works too.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little change in your code will do the trick.
Here is the solution I found to obtain your expected output

```
num_nodes = 3
nodelist = list(range(1, num_nodes + 1))
edgelist = []
for i in nodelist:
    for j in nodelist:
        if i == j:
            edgelist.append((i, j, 0))
        elif i < j:
            rand = random.randint(5, 25)
            edgelist.append((i, j, rand))
            edgelist.append((j, i, rand))
print(sorted(edgelist))
```

This code outputs :

```
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 15), (1, 3, 15), (2, 1, 15), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 21), (3, 1, 15), (3, 2, 21), (3, 3, 0)]
```